# radio button on flutter won't change data (using WebView)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, webview, radio-button

radio button on flutter won't change data (using WebView)

I have a simple quiz application using a radio button on flutter, temporary dummy data is used and displayed in the form of a webview. but when I try to click next, only a few questions change.

[image: Data Question]

**Next Question Quiz**

[image: Next Question]

**display quiz in the form of webview**
[image: View Data]

[image: Sample Quiz]

[image]